# Django - jinja syntax help - how do i pass the value of {{ title }} into the href url args?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, cs50

so i have this html :

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  {% autoescape off %}
    <p>{{ entry|safe }}</p>
  {% endautoescape%}
  <br>
  <a href="{% url 'edit' 'cat' %}"><button type="button" name="button">Edit</button></a>
{% endblock %}
```

i want the url 'edit' to also get the value of the {{ title}}  - instead of 'cat' ..i just used this value to test the rest of the code, but i don`t want to hard code it like that ...

here are my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:title>", views.title, name="title"),
    path("edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("error/", views.error, name="error"),
    path("new/", views.new, name="new"),
]
```

this is the code in views.py :

```
def title(request, title):
    entry = util.get_entry(title)
    if entry == None:
        return redirect("error")
    entry_html = md.convert(entry)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/title.html", {
        "entry": entry_html
    })


def edit(request, title):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # get the changes from the user
        form = EditEntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            # save the entry and redirect to the updated page
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return redirect("title", title=title)
        else:
            redirect("edit", title=title)

    entry = util.get_entry(title)
    form = EditEntryForm(initial={'content': entry})
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "form": form
    })
```

as i said the code works as intended if i hard code the value of the title ....how do i get {{ title }} in the href url ?

Comment: `{% url 'edit' title %}` pass it without parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to pass it in as:

```
{% url 'edit' title %}
```

…or you may need to specify the argument name:

```
{% url 'edit' title=title %}
```

See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/) in the documentation for more information.

Comment: i tried that....that is where my confusion rests....i read the documentation and all that but can't seem to find an answer...if i type `{% url 'edit' title %}` i get this error `NoReverseMatch at /Django
Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<title>[^/]+)$'] `  when trying to access the title.html page .... and if i do `{% url 'edit' title=title %}` i get this error `NoReverseMatch at /Django
Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'title': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<title>[^/]+)$']`

Comment: OHHH ! i got it ......in the `def title(request, title)` function i was only passing a value for the `"entry"` and i had no variable `"title"`